# What is meant by front and back pitch of an armature winding?

Tags: dc-motor, electric-machine, winding, rotor

I searched the internet for these definitions and found a common definition in all websites:

**Back Pitch**-
A coil advances on the back of the armature. This advancement is measured in terms of armature conductors and is called back pitch. It is equal to the number difference of the conductor connected to a given segment of the commutator.

**Front Pitch-**
The number of armature conductors or elements spanned by a coil on the front is called front pitch.

I din't get these definitions. I don't understand what is meant by "back" of the armature.
Can you please explain me the two definitions?

Answer (score 4):

All fractional windings have an inherent **front and back offset pitch** as it is the current switched during commutation that results in >5000 deg C air detonation (arc) and carbon brush, copper armature that heats up with temperature wear factors and its fractional duty cycle that determines odd or even harmonic content which affects eddy current losses in the steel laminations as eddy current losses rise with frequency.

This is how some harmonic content is suppressed and reduction of copper size, cost and copper losses are done in motor/generators.  It is a result of creating **fractional pitch windings** that are smaller than the mechanical pitch of the magnetic field defined by the key slots.

The other benefit is by changing the duty cycle of the square wave current is the decision to shunt 5th or 7th harmonics  by choosing a fractional pitch winding of 4/5th and 6/7th fractional pitch ratio respectively. Some use a compromise of 5/6th pitch to partially attenuate both 5th and 7th harmonics which cause eddy current losses.

Now this fractional winding loop can be staggered such that the leading and trailing edges are different for each application depending on dynamic loads and harmonic issues.

A short answer looks like this.

**Here only a back pitch is shown with no front pitch in a fractional winding.**
[image]

[For further research and more details, you may consider here](https://www.google.com/search?q=armature%20conductors%20or%20elements%20spanned%20by%20a%20coil&num=30&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-8um61-zaAhUJ1oMKHadvCtkQ_AUICigB&biw=752&bih=722#imgrc=1GEngO4VbvlyDM:)

If you can imagine this loop shifted you get a lead and trail edge offset called Front and Back Pitch.

Since inductive currents lag voltage the phase of the commutators is shifted to reduce the switching arc current at a minimal loss of torque but considerable improvement in switching losses and heat rise.

### Other info

This is related but different with brushless motors ( like DC fans) using Hall sensors and PWM phase control, but for different reasons to maximimize speed and torque with the phase of commutation.  I have often seen design faults ( even major suppliers like Nydec) where fans with misaligned Hall commutation sensors caused the fan *to fail to start* either by heat shift or aging or process margin flaws.  This results in commutating too close to the zero current or zero torque threshold and it results in dithering back and forth or simply stalled with no torque, unless given a gentle nudge. **This happens only because there is a permanent magnet for each resting pole position.**  It may try to go backwards then forwards or just stalls with no torque. If there is a pitch offset i.e. **front pitch** then it is gauranteed to rotate in any starting position. I once found 1% of fans failed for this flaw and designed a start stop test so that in 30 seconds a batch of fans could be tested for commutation faults then gave the test jig design to the factory and said we will disqualify them if they do not fix the problem by performing my start-stop test before shipment. They did and then fixed their design/process margin flaw and yields resumed to 100% due to Hall Sensor location offset or if you like, I might call it the **"resting forward pitch commutation offset"**

For brushed high current motors, the fault might be that brushes or armatures wear out prematurely or the harmonic content makes the steel laminations too hot in high power motor/generators when the wrong fractional winding is choosen for a certain applications.

Answer (score 0):

The side where commutator segments are placed is called front and its opposite side is  called back.Now assume we placed one side of a coil in an armature slot.If you want to identify the second side of the same coil how can you identify it among the many wires??All you have to do is find the one connected to the first one directly.How can you do this? By looking at the back.So it is back pitch.Now you have placed the second side of first coil in the armature  slot,now where to start the first side of second coil?We know that the second side of first coil and first side of second coil are connected to the same commutator segment.So all you have to do is check in the front side.So it is called front pitch